# get number of like for a video with facebook fql

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

how can I have the number of like about a id video?

I am using this query but it's not working:

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id=10151815700693876
```

Error:

```
   {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id=10151815700693876", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 803
  }
}
```

Comment: the solution founded in the other post not work.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query would result back in an array of likes by user_id. You will have to take the total count of the array in order to determine the likes count.

Instead simply use https://graph.facebook.com/postid/likes and use 'summary' as a parameter and pass its value as 1.

You will get a response summary with a field "total_count" and that's your total likes count for the post.